# How to remove an Array of ObjectID's in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collections, campgrounds and reviews while deleting an review it stays in object array in campgrounds as an ObjectID ref and i can't find a way to delete them from there.

I tried

```
db.campgrounds.update({ title: "Ancient Hunting Camp" }, { $pull:{id:"60f8293044b0cc40c409f2f7"}})
db.campgrounds.update({ title: "Ancient Hunting Camp" }, { $pull: {reviews:{id:"60f8293044b0cc40c409f2f7"}}})
db.campgrounds.update({ title: "Ancient Hunting Camp" }, { $pullAll: {reviews:[]}},{multi:true})
db.campgrounds.update({ title: "Ancient Hunting Camp" }, { $pull: { reviews: {}}}, {multi:true})
db.campgrounds.update({ _id: "603d7a10f969af31484fb56e" }, { $pull: { reviews: "ratings"}})
db.campgrounds.update({ _id: "603d7a10f969af31484fb56e" }, { $pull: { reviews: ObjectId("60f976cd6132a91a20bd6679") }}
```

I've had these results

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

or

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

or

```
WriteResult({
"nMatched" : 0,
"nUpserted" : 0,
"nModified" : 0,
"writeError" : {
"code" : 2,
"errmsg" : "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"
}
})`
```

Campground Schema

```
    const CampgroundSchema = new Schema({

    title: String,
    image: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String,
    location: String,
    tel: Number,
    website: String,
    email: String,

    reviews: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Review'
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: You have to match the type, too.  "603d7a10f969af31484fb56e" is a string, not an ObjectId